# RecyclerView - populate animation -> move all elements to target position from one origin

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve an animation similar to the one in QuickPic. When I show the content of an `RecyclerView` I want that all items animate to their target position starting at one origin point (the same for all items)

Does anyone know how I could make such a population animation?

Comment: I don't think they are doing any `populate animation`. They are somehow keeping the Images GridView fragment and they are doing `scale and zoom` animation on whole fragment which is pre-filled with images. If you clean cache of the app and start again and closely monitor when going into folder first time and second time, you will see.

Comment: I guess it's itemAnimator of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the origin point has coordinates of `(x, y)`. Then we can animate all views from this point to their target position with this code:

```
recycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(final View view,
      final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom,
      final int oldLeft, final int oldTop, final int oldRight, final int oldBottom) {
    recycler.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    for (int i = 0, count = recycler.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
      final View child = recycler.getChildAt(i);
      child.setTranslationX(x - child.getLeft());
      child.setTranslationY(y - child.getTop());
      child.animate()
          .translationX(0f)
          .translationY(0f)
          .setStartDelay(5 * i * i)
          .setDuration(DURATION)
          .withLayer()
          .start();
    }
  }
});
```

Here we position all the children of the `RecyclerView` at the origin point and animate them to their target positions. We start all the animations after the `RecyclerView` layouts itself so that children are created and their positions are computed.

An animation delay set to `5 * i * i` is just an example of how the delay can be calculated. You can change this formula to anything you want or remove the delay if you don't need it.

Comment: This is something I can really work with, that's the idea I needed. Thank you very much. Even works after setting the items and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` with the same listener...

Comment: I still have one problem: how to control z order of the animated children during the animation only? I want to have the the z order to reflect the order in the recycler view during the animation, i.e. the first item should be before the second and so on... Currently it's vice versa... I can change this with setting the z order accordingly before starting the animation, but how would I do it on android api < 21?

Comment: Call `RecyclerView.setChildDrawingOrderCallback()` and provide your order.

Comment: Returning `return childCount - i - 1;` for this callback works. Thanks